# Why is there a [missing-scene] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

While scrolling to the least popular tags, I came across the [missing-scene](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/missing-scene) tag, with no apparent questions. **Was this tag popular at one point or why does it exist?**

Comment: I don't know if it was ever popular, but I just happened to notice the tag being removed from [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28360/what-happened-to-this-scene)

Comment: The single use of this tag was created [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/28360/revisions) and deleted a few hours ago. Since it's not attached to a question, it'll get roomba'd into oblivion shortly.

Comment: R.I.P. [TAG:missing-scene]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### There isn't.

During a discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe) about the possibility of a [scene-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scene-identification) tag, I noticed that there was a [missing-scene](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/missing-scene) tag with a single question. I then [edited](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/28360/revisions) that question to remove the tag. You just happened to notice it at precisely the time when it no longer existed but was still shown in the system due to caching. As of now, it no longer appears in the tags list.

Comment: You mean the [tag:missing-scene] tag is... *missing*? :)

Comment: let's rename it to missing-tag